# how to can I use element name including dot for jQuery form valiator plugin

Tags: validation, jquery-validate

I am using jQuery and form validator plugin and it works fine except one page shown below.

```
HTML:
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="frmReg" class="form-horizontal" novalidate="novalidate">
                <input type="hidden" name="mode" id="mode" value="insert">
                <input type="hidden" name="fileName" id="fileName">
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label id="fileLabel" class="control-label">*File Name</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input type="file" name="file" id="file" placeholder="Select file" required="required" class="valid">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label">*Package Name</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input type="text" name="id.appId" id="appId" placeholder="Type group ID" tabindex="0" class="valid">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label">*Application Title</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input type="text" name="appName" id="appName" placeholder="Type application name" class="valid">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label">*Version</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        **<input type="text" name="id.version" id="version" placeholder="Type version" tabindex="0" class="valid">**
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Description</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <textarea name="description" id="description" placeholder="Type description" class="valid"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn">Close</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </form>

JS: 
$("#frmReg").validate({
        ignore: "", //for hidden field
        rules: {
            version: {
                required: true,
                number: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            version: {
                required: "Enter version number",
                number: "Decimal numbers only allowed."
            }
        }
    });

    **$("#frmReg").validate().element("#version");**
```

It works when I use 'version' as the input name but I have to use 'id.version' as input name rather than 'version' because of server-side framework. But when I use the name, the validation code always  returns true, even when I type any special characters and alphabets.
How can I still use id.version for the element?
Your answer would be appreciated.

Comment: I could not find any solution by myself, so I just added hidden field.
<input type="hidden" placeholder="Type group ID" id='id_version' name="id.version">

And I copied value from version to id_version.
$('#id_version').val($('#version').val());

Answer (score 0):

[As per the documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/reference/)...

> **Fields with complex names (brackets, dots)**
>
> If your form consists of fields using names that aren't legal JavaScript identifiers, you have to quote those names when using the rules option

Simply put quotes around the `name` containing dots...

```
$("#frmReg").validate({
    ignore: "", //for hidden field
    rules: {
        'id.version': {
            required: true,
            number: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        'id.version': {
            required: "Enter version number",
            number: "Decimal numbers only allowed."
        }
    }
});
```

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/A2ZdL/**